# Simplifying a type signature without using associated types

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Is there a way to simplify the type signature here

```
pub struct OrderBook<T: PriceLevel, U: PriceLadder<T>> {
    levels: U,
    phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

such that

```
type HashBook = OrderBook<LinkedHashLevel, HashmapLadder<LinkedHashLevel>>;
```

can be written as follows?

```
type HashBook = OrderBook<LinkedHashLevel, HashmapLadder>;
```

I'm aware of associated types but want to be able to use a single price ladder with different price level implementations.

Complete compilable code below...

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct OrderBook<T: PriceLevel, U: PriceLadder<T>> {
    levels: U,
    phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T: PriceLevel, U: PriceLadder<T>> OrderBook<T, U> {}

type HashBook = OrderBook<LinkedHashLevel, HashmapLadder<LinkedHashLevel>>;

pub trait PriceLevel {
    fn new() -> Self where Self: Sized;
}

pub trait PriceLadder<T: PriceLevel> {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

pub struct LinkedHashLevel {
}

impl PriceLevel for LinkedHashLevel {
    fn new() -> Self {
        LinkedHashLevel {}
    }
}

pub struct HashmapLadder<T: PriceLevel> {
    levels: HashMap<u64, T>,
}

impl<T: PriceLevel> PriceLadder<T> for HashmapLadder<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        HashmapLadder { levels: HashMap::new() }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: This is missing a number of other types. There;s no definition of `HashMapLadder` here, for example.

Comment: Added compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is not necessary to change the type signature. Considering what you sad:

> I'm aware of associated types but want to be able to use a single **price ladder with different implementations of price level**.

Maybe it is enough to create a type type alias parametrized by the price level implementation and with a fixed price ladder:

```
type HashBook<Level> = OrderBook<Level, HashmapLadder<Level>>;
```